# Is there a possibility to change when alert rule is active?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm writing an Elasticsearch query for alerting using the "Rules and connectors" function.

Currently, the rule can only be enabled (active 24/7) or disabled (never active).

I want to create rules that could only be triggered during the day. (from 8AM to 17PM and similar)

Is it possible to edit the query to make the rule active for 8 hours or less?

At the moment my alert query looks like this:

```
{
   "query" : {
       "bool":{
           "must":[
               {"match":{"fields.Operation":"EndPaymentActivity"}
               },
               {"match":{"level":"Information"}}
               ],
           "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
               "source": "doc['@timestamp'].value.hourOfDay >= params.startHour && doc['@timestamp'].value.hourOfDay <= params.endHour",
               "params": {
                 "startHour": 7,
                 "endHour": 9
               }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
       }
   }
}
```

It keeps triggering during night, when there are no payments made. How can I set the rule to be active not 24/7, but only for 8 hours every day?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

As of release 8.4 there is no such thing as a calendar function to enable / disable the alerts in kibana.

But you should be able to build one with [watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/watcher-ui.html) + [kibana's alerting api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/disable-rule-api.html)

Comment: I'm using Kibana v7.16.2, is there a calendar available?

Comment: No I don't think so